# C snake game colliding with itself

Tags: c

I followed this guide to make a snake game in c++, but I made mine in c.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSoLD9mVXTA

I only have one issue otherwise i'm set. I can't quite get the snake to collide with itself properly and I can't figure out why it's working for the guy in the video but the identical code isn't working out for me.

The code is ugly and not well organised. Don't judge me, I'm still learning!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int gameOver = 1;
const int width = 20;
const int height = 20;
typedef enum {STOP = 0, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN} eDirection;
eDirection dir;
int x, y, fruitX, fruitY, score;

int tailX[100], tailY[100];
int nTail;


void Setup(){
    gameOver = 0;
    dir = STOP;
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;
    fruitX = rand() % width;
    fruitY = rand() % height;
    score = 0;

}

void Draw(){

    system("cls");

    for(int i = 0; i < width +3; i++)
        printf("#");
        printf("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){

        for(int j = 0; j < width+2; j++){


                if(j == 0){
                    printf("#");
                }
                if(j == width+1){
                    printf("#");
                }

                if(i == y && j == x){
                    printf("*");

                }else if(i == fruitY && j == fruitX){
                    printf("F");

                }else{

                    int print = 0;
                    for(int k = 0; k < nTail; k++){

                        if(tailX[k] == j && tailY[k] == i){

                            printf("*");
                            print = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!print){
                        printf(" ");
                    }
                }

            }
            printf("\n");
        }

    for(int i = 0; i < width +3; i++)
        printf("#");
        printf("\n");


    printf("\nScore : %d",score);
}

void Input(){

   if (kbhit()){
        switch (getch()){
            case 'a':
                dir = LEFT;
                break;
            case 'd':
                dir = RIGHT;
                break;
            case 'w':
                dir = UP;
                break;
            case 's':
                dir = DOWN;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
   }

}

void Logic(){


    int prevX = tailX[0];
    int prevY = tailY[0];
    int prev2X, prev2Y;
    tailX[0] = x;
    tailY[0] = y;

    for(int 1 = 0; i < nTail; i++){
        prev2X = tailX[i];
        prev2Y = tailY[i];
        tailX[i] = prevX;
        tailY[i] = prevY;
        prevX = prev2X;
        prevY = prev2Y;

    }

    if(x > width || x < 0 || y > height-1 || y < 0){
        gameOver = 1;
    }
    if(x == fruitX && y == fruitY){

        fruitX = rand() % width;
        fruitY = rand() % height;
        score = score + 10;

        nTail++;
    }
   //collision code
    for(int i = 0; i < nTail; i++)
        if(tailX[i] == x && tailY[i] == y){
            gameOver = 1;
    }


    switch(dir){

        case LEFT:
            x--;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            x++;
            break;
        case UP:
            y--;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            y++;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }



}

int main(){

    Setup();
        while(!gameOver){
            Draw();
            Input();
            Logic();
            Sleep(100);
        }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use your debugger. Also, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How do i use a debugger?

Comment: Note: Signatures like `int main()` are deprecated and should not be used in C anymore. Instead use prototype-style signatures (e.g. `int main(void)`).

Comment: `for(int 1 = 0; i < nTail; i++){` can't be your real code! How does your real code look?

Comment: Also - what exactly do mean by `collide with itself properly` - do you mean that it never collides or is it some special cases where it doesn't collide?

Answer (score 1):

Your program fails as soon as you hit a fruit.

**Explanation**

When your code starts you have no tail, i.e. `nTail` is `0`.

In `Logic()` you do:

```
tailX[0] = x;
tailY[0] = y;
```

so index zero is set to the current position (even though `nTail` is zero).

When you hit the fruit you do:

```
if(x == fruitX && y == fruitY){

    fruitX = rand() % width;
    fruitY = rand() % height;
    score = score + 10;

    nTail++;    <---- Here you increment nTail so it becomes 1
}
```

Then you do

```
//collision code
for(int i = 0; i < nTail; i++)
    if(tailX[i] == x && tailY[i] == y){
        gameOver = 1;
}
```

since `nTail` is `1` it is the same as:

```
    if(tailX[0] == x && tailY[0] == y){
        gameOver = 1;
    }
```

and that is exactly the assignment you made in the start of `Logic`. In other words - it is `true` and `gameover` will become 1.

Maybe a solution is to start from `1` instead of `0`:

```
//collision code
for(int i = 1; i < nTail; i++)
       ^^^
```

Another problem related to the collision detection.

```
if(x == fruitX && y == fruitY){

    fruitX = rand() % width;
    fruitY = rand() % height;
    score = score + 10;

    nTail++;    <---- Here you increment nTail but no value is
                      written to tailX[nTail-1] and tailY[nTail-1] 
                      after the increment
}
//collision code
for(int i = 0; i < nTail; i++)
    if(tailX[i] == x && tailY[i] == y){  <-- Here you use tailX[nTail-1] and tailY[nTail-1]
        gameOver = 1;
}
```

So when you have just taken a fruit, you compare with values not part of the tail.

Comment: If i set the for loop in collision i can only collide with myself if i have nTail length be 3 and i got back into myself. I followed what you said and i still can't get collision to work properly.

Comment: How did you change this line `for(int 1 = 0; i < nTail; i++){` ? What is the real code that you are using?

Comment: How did you change the for-loop? To start from `1` or ... ?

Comment: yes, i made the loop start with 1 instead. Now the snake can only collide with itself if it's a certain length. Oh and btw how would i go about making it so that if i go left i can't go right into myself and same with right up down.